# NSCollectionView animated re-layout

Tags: swift, macos, animation, drag-and-drop, nscollectionview

I'm creating a simple app for Mac (10.11). I have NSCollectionView, on which one will sort objects. I've added Drag&Drop support, but NSCollectionView does not animate. Instead, it reloads its content.

```
    func collectionView(collectionView: NSCollectionView, writeItemsAtIndexes indexes: NSIndexSet, toPasteboard pasteboard: NSPasteboard) -> Bool {
        let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(indexes)
        pasteboard.setData(data, forType: "business_drag")

        return true
    }


    func collectionView(collectionView: NSCollectionView, validateDrop draggingInfo: NSDraggingInfo, proposedIndex proposedDropIndex: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>, dropOperation proposedDropOperation: UnsafeMutablePointer<NSCollectionViewDropOperation>) -> NSDragOperation {
        return NSDragOperation.Move
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: NSCollectionView, acceptDrop draggingInfo: NSDraggingInfo, index: Int, dropOperation: NSCollectionViewDropOperation) -> Bool {

        Swift.print("acceptDrop")

        let pasteboard = draggingInfo.draggingPasteboard()
        let data = pasteboard.dataForType("business_drag")
        let indexes = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data!) as! NSIndexSet
        let draggedCell = indexes.firstIndex

        let old = NSIndexPath(forItem: draggedCell, inSection: 0)
        let new = NSIndexPath(forItem: index, inSection: 0)

        collectionView.animator().moveItemAtIndexPath(old, toIndexPath: new)

        // uncommenting this lines makes collectionView reload its conntent
//       let object = collectionView.content.removeAtIndex(draggedCell)
//      collectionView.content.insert(object, atIndex: index)

        return true
    }
```

I've downloaded sample code from AppleDeveloper Portal, but it's written in Objective-C

Comment: Sorry to late reply, which Apple sample code are you referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things that you will need to make sure:

1. Before calling `moveItemAtIndexPath`, make sure you did not change the duration of current animation context to zero (by default it is 0.25). You can change the value using `NSAnimationContext.currentContext().duration`
2. Make sure you have add the CALayer to the Scroll View (not Collection View). You can either turn on in Interface Builder or programmatically using `wantsLayer`

An example can be referred to the following repository, which is a translated version of Apple Sample Project, CocoaSlideCollection, which is a demo for NSCollectionView 2015. Check the `BrowserWindow.xib` for CALayer.

https://github.com/ooper-shlab/CocoaSlideCollection-Swift

Besides, I have created a video tutorial, check the 19'30" on this

Youtube: https://youtu.be/fEuiLhYerBA

Source Code: https://github.com/harryworld/NSCollectionView-DragDrop